# RRAS Blocks Exchange

Tags: exchange, rras

Injust managed to setup RRAS on our windows 200 r2 server which also acts as an exchange server 2010. The RRAs was setup to allow VPN connections.

When I enable the service (RAS) i think i can connect fine via VPN and access both internet and our network drives. The problem is that as soon as I enable the service, exchange goes offline. I did the exchange diagnostic and it seems that RRAS is using port 25 which prevents exchange from working. As soon as i disable the servicemthen exchange goes back online.

Any ideas what to do? The VPN is imtended to allow people to access local drives and that's it...

Many thanks.

Antonis

Answer (score 4):

Exchange servers can only be exchange servers. Do not install any other roles on them. It's not supported, and as you've noticed - it won't work.

Comment: But there has to be a way to make it work.

Comment: @Antonis Yes. Get another server, or virtualize.

Comment: Ok will try wi virtualizing. Thx guys.